Why does Desmos give a small, nonzero value for $\sin(5\pi/6) - 1/2$?
I type $\sin(5\pi/6)$ and it says $0.5$, which is completely normal.
However, when I add "$-1/2$," the result is $−5.5511151231×10^{-17}$.
Why is it happening and am I doing something wrong?
picture 1 picture 2

Computers are bad at subtraction. This kind of thing commonly happens with floating point arithmetic, and you should avoid subtractions and divisions as much as you can in your queries.

about the original title:  "Weird has a weird spelling"

@paulina I agree that this issue is out there but technically this answer is wrong so why do people say that this is a known 'paradox' instead of saying desmos has flaws, like, when wrong answers have become normal? photomath for example gives the right answer

@paulina, there is an interesting paradox. Floating-point arithmetic as used usually by computers gives you the exact result for x-y if x/2 <= y <= 2x. The problem is there is a tiny error in sin(5pi/6). The subtraction just makes it visible.

@Alex I have never heard people call floating point errors a "paradox", they are well understood and even mentioned in the first floating point standard all the way back in the 50s.

@gnasher729 that is true. my comment below is probably a better explanation for what is happening here, but the advice here still holds.

These sorts of errors are fundamental to the way computers store real numbers. There are many explanations of "IEEE-754 Floating Point", so I won't go into the details, but the essential issue is that the computer only allocates a finite number of bits (ones and zeroes) to each number, so there's some rounding error inherent to the process. With these limitations, $\sin(x)$ can't be computed exactly for arbitrary $x$, $\pi$ is not exactly $\pi$, and $\sin(5 \pi / 6)$ is not exactly $0.5$.
A classic example of the limitations of floating-point arithmetic can be found by evaluating $0.1 + 0.2$ in nearly any programming language:
> 0.1 + 0.2
< 0.30000000000000004

I'm not 100% certain that Desmos uses standard floating-point numbers, but the underlying reason is almost certainly the same: $\sin(5 \pi/6)$ is not computed exactly due to the limitations of computer arithmetic.
It would actually be possible to get an exact value for $\sin(5 \pi/6)$ if the algorithm worked symbolically, using trigonometric theorems to evaluate the $\sin$ expression exactly when possible, but evidently it does not (at least in this case).

The reason Desmos does this is because it uses the $\sin(x)$ Taylor series to calculate $\sin(x)$.
To elaborate, Desmos calculates $\sum_{i=0}^{\text{Large Number}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{i}}{\left(2i+1\right)!}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^{\left(2i+1\right)}$, which $\textit{approximates}$ to $0.5$.
When the result of the summation is subtracted by $0.5$, you get a very small number that is close to $0$ for your answer.

This doesn't explain why Desmos didn't output 0.5000000000001 or similar when asked for the sine by itself?

How do you know it uses the Taylor series specifically? That would be somewhat unusual for general numeric computation.

I assume that for the initial query, desmos simply knows that $\sin(5\pi/6) = 1/2$ on its own, which is why it outputs the exact value. If it's part of a larger expression, it likely uses approximations instead, which is how the result came to be.

The bigger problem may be that 5 pi / 6 is calculated with some error. And you use a Chebyshev polynomial which has much smaller errors.

Programming language libraries and computer algebra systems use much more sophisticated methods than just Taylor series to calculate transcendental functions. To understand why, consider that  they are required to give answers to within the least significant bit for $\sin,x$ for huge values of $x$.

Note that it's sufficient to just find $\sin$ on the interval $[0, \pi / 2]$, but that the Taylor series is centered at 0, and so converges more quickly on one end of the interval than the other. If one were to use a polynomial approximation $P$, it would make more sense to do something like minimize $\int_0^{\pi/2} |P(x) - \sin(x)| ; dx$ than optimize around $0$. Though polynomial approximations are not the only (or preferred) method (e.g. CORDIC).

@paulina Desmos rounds to about 12 sig figs when displaying the result, but not storing the result, as shown here.

@Invariance You are probably correct; OP gives no source
